# How to check the port number of the hadoop services

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, port, bigdata

How to check the port number of the hadoop services eg: port number for hive, oozie, sqoop, pig etc. I heard each hadoop service has a port number.

Answer (score 1):

Normally Port use to get configured in the Configuration Files it self, available in either under "/etc/hadoop/conf/" or "/usr/local/hadoop/conf/" location "hadoop" with respected names like "pig/hive/sqoop" etc.
The Configuration named as "hdfs-site.xml/core-site.xml/hive-site.xml/mapred-site.xml...etc"
Some of the default Ports Used by Hadoop and it's Eco Systmems are:

```
Daemon                      Default Port    Configuration Paramete
Namenode                    50070           dfs.http.address
Datanodes                   50075           dfs.datanode.http.address
Secondarynamenode           50090           dfs.secondary.http.address
Backup/Checkpoint node      50105           dfs.backup.http.address
Jobracker                   50030           mapred.job.tracker.http.address
Tasktrackers                50060           mapred.task.tracker.http.address
```

Also Check Reference: [MORE DETAIL PORTS](http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/enterprise/5-2-x/topics/cdh_ig_ports_cdh5.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of Cloudera Distribution of Hadoop post numbers for each components : [Ports Used by Components of CDH 5](http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_ports_cdh5.html)

Comment: There appears 2 Ip's 1 starts with 10.xxx.xxx.xxx and other starts with 192.xxx.xxx.xxx what is the use of both the Ip's? etho is 10. Ip

Comment: @Naveen The question is about posts number. I did not understand.

Comment: Alright. I got the port number for hive metastore its 9083. now whats the command to check the status of hadoop service status through command line. I know that this port number is required for that

Comment: @Naveen Port number is required for Web UI. In command line, you can check hadoop services by `jps` if they are up and running.

Comment: when I type jps it shows 59328 -- process information unavailable
38689 -- process information unavailable
59137 -- process information unavailable
47399 Jps
56746 -- process information unavailable
OS version I am using is Linux 2.6.39-400.264.1.el6uek.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-ol6-builder-06) (gcc version 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)

Comment: @Naveen Remove `/tmp/hsperfdata_{username}` folder or clear /tmp folder and run `jps` again.